# filter an async Table in Angular

Tags: angular, angularfire2

My Data is coming from an database (firestore) and I would like to use them in an async table. I use angular2-datatable for none async Data. My approach to use it in a async way does show me the table with the correct data but I cant use sorting on it.

```
<table class="table table-striped" 
       [mfData]="users | async | dataFilter : filterQuery" 
        #mf="mfDataTable" 
        [mfRowsOnPage]="10" 
        [(mfSortBy)]="timestamp" 
        [(mfSortOrder)]="desc">
</table>
```

So my question. 
1) Can I acutally use the sorting with async data and 2) What are am I doing wrong?

example data:

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "timestamp": XXX
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "timestamp": XXX
  },
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "timestamp": XXX
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the pipe code that you're using ?

Comment: Read the warning in angular's documentation on why there's no built in sort & filter pipe and what you should do instead for sorting and filtering. https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe